# Plot a histogram, based on percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, percentile

I have a frame with the folowing structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(1, 13, size=1000),
                   'VALUE': np.random.randint(0, 300, size=1000)})
```

How could i plot the graph, where on the X-axis there will be percentiles (10%, 20%,..90%)
and on the Y-axis there should be quantity of values, that lies between percentile ticks , for example 20%-30%
And ther must be a seperate plot for every ID (and different percentiles values also)

i've found percentiles and stuck
`q = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]`
`df.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].quantile(q)`

I guess the plot should look like a histogram for VALUE parameter, but with percentage on X axis instead of numeric values

Answer (score 2):

```
q = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]

for name, group in df.groupby('ID'):  # Groupy by ID column
    _, bins = pd.qcut(group.VALUE, q, retbins=True, grid=False)  # Splits data in defined quantiles
    plt.figure()
    group.VALUE.hist(bins=bins)  # Plots histogram of data with specified bins
    ax.set_xticks(q, [f'{str(x) * 100}%' for x in q])  # format ticks (NOT TESTED)   
    plt.show()
```

Not capturing the output plots here, because they are alot. It produces the plot you want, but you will also need to adapt the ticks and formatting.

To achieve a normalized plot, with y-Axis ranging from 0-100%, you would need to normalize your data before plotting (maybe somehting like `group.VALUE.count() / df.VALUE.count()`

Comment: gives me a ValueError: Bin edges must be uniuque: array([ 7.1, 8., .....])

Comment: Hmm, tested it with the sample data you provided, can't reproduce that

Comment: I guess it's because in some groups in my real data there could be very small amount of values. Less than 10, i think

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Quantile'] = pd.qcut(df.VALUE, q=np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
tmp_df = df.pivot_table(index='Quantile', columns='ID', aggfunc='count')
tmp_df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, figsize=(10,10))
plt.show()
```

Output, each subplot is the quantile count for each ID.

[image]

Comment: what is Quantile? In every ID there must be individual values for every percentile

Comment: So the difficulty is in grouping by IDs - when i try to qcut on any of them - i get an ValueError "Bin edges must be unique", beacuse of small amount of values in some groups

Comment: Review your bins, maybe `bins = sorted(list(set(bins)))`. The other statement is not a problem, it will shows as `Nan` on the grouping and `0` on plot.

Comment: @Quang Hoang...nice one!!